# Joining tables - Matching a number with a part of a comma separated list of numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a SQL query that joins two tables - Holidays containing details about holiday packages and Flights containing flight details. Please find a simplified extract of both tables below.

Holidays:

```
Destination       Departure            Duration               Board_Type
    CFU              GLA                   7                     Full
    ATH              MAN                   14                    Half
    ZTH              BRS                   10                    Full
```

Flights:

```
Flight Num      Destination    Departure    Duration_Switch     Duration
   2490             CFU          EDI              IN            7,8,10,11
   2491             HER          LHR              IN               9
   2492             ATH          LTN            NOT IN            10,14
```

I am trying to join these tables on a number of criteria, including the duration of the holiday. In Holidays, Duration simply gives me the length of that specific package. The Flights table is more complicated - if the duration_switch is 'IN', then Duration gives a list of the holiday durations traveling on that flight. If the duration_switch is 'NOT IN', then Duration gives a list of the holiday durations NOT travelling on that flight.

I am trying to create a JOIN condition such that if f.duration_switch is 'IN' the tables join if the holiday Duration is in the list of flight Durations or if f.duration_switch is 'NOT IN' then the list of flight Durations. If the duration_switch is NULL, that means all durations are serviced by that flight, so I want to join those as well.

I tried the following:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM holidays h
RIGHT JOIN flights  f
        ON h.destination = f.destination
       AND h.departure   = f.departure
       AND ((f.duration_operator = 'IN' AND f.duration LIKE '%'||h.duration||'%') 
        OR (f.duration_operator = 'NOT IN' AND f.duration NOT LIKE '%'||h.duration||'%') 
        OR f.duration_operator IS NULL)
```

The problem with this code is that, for example, if h.Duration is 4, that will match with a j.Duration of let's say 10,11,14 because it contains the digit 4.

Comment: What result do you expect, based on sample data you posted? Because, the first two conditions you wrote (joining DESTINATION and DEPARTURE) cause no rows to be retrieved; no *departures* match.

Comment: What @Littlefoot said, plus your query references `duration_operator` whereas your CREATE TABLE statement has `Duration_Switch`. You're asking people to spend their time helping you, so you really should invest some of your time making sure your question is complete and correct. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As I said (as a comment), sample data you posted is somewhat *wrong* because no departures match so - regardless of what you write later, that condition makes no rows to be retrieved.

That's why I slightly modified sample data; have a look at the following code, see whether it makes sense. The idea is: split `duration` (which is stored as a comma-separated-values list) into rows so that you could join it to `duration` in another table.

I don't know what `duration_operator` is; there's none in sample data.

Here it goes:

```
SQL> with
  2  holidays (destination, departure, duration) as
  3    (select 'CFU', 'GLA', 7  from dual union all
  4     select 'ATH', 'LTN', 14 from dual union all
  5     select 'ZTH', 'BRS', 10 from dual
  6    ),
  7  flights (flight_num, destination, departure, duration_switch, duration) as
  8    (select 2490, 'CFU', 'GLA', 'IN'    , '7,8,10,11' from dual union all
  9     select 2491, 'HER', 'LHR', 'IN'    , '9'         from dual union all
 10     select 2492, 'ATH', 'LTN', 'NOT IN', '10,14'     from dual
 11    ),
 12  --
 13  -- split all DURATIONs from FLIGHTS to rows, so that you could join them with HOLIDAYS
 14  flisplit as
 15    (select flight_num,
 16            destination,
 17            departure,
 18            duration_switch,
 19            regexp_substr(duration, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) duration
 20     from flights join
 21          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 22                              connect by level <= regexp_count(duration, ',') + 1
 23                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist )) on 1 = 1
 24    )
 25  select f.flight_num,
 26         h.destination,
 27         h.departure,
 28         h.duration,
 29         f.duration_switch
 30  from holidays h join flisplit f on h.destination = f.destination
 31                                 and h.departure   = f.departure
 32      and (   h.duration =  case when duration_switch = 'IN' then f.duration end
 33           or h.duration <> case when duration_switch = 'NOT IN' then f.duration end
 34          );

FLIGHT_NUM DES DEP   DURATION DURATI
---------- --- --- ---------- ------
      2490 CFU GLA          7 IN
      2492 ATH LTN         14 NOT IN

SQL>
```